# Does an array have a dimension limit?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to fill an array dynamically. The software opens a file in binary mode, gets the dimension of the file and initializes an array to store the binary contents of the file opened. Then it creates a new file, in which it puts the contents of the array.

This works, but only with files smaller that 1 MBytes.

**Do arrays have a maximum dimension?**

Here's the code:

```
void read(char* address){

   int i;
   int d;
   int size;
   unsigned char standard = 0x00;

   // get file dimension:
   FILE* sizer = fopen(address, "r+b");
   fseek(sizer, 0, SEEK_END);
   size = ftell(sizer);
   fseek(sizer, 0, SEEK_SET);
   fclose(sizer);

   // initialization of array: 
   unsigned char loaded[size];

   // filling the array with the binary contents of file:
   FILE* load = fopen(address, "r+b");
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
    fseek(load, i, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&loaded[i], sizeof(standard), 1, load);
   }
   fclose(load);

   // Copy the binary contents of array, inside a new file:
   FILE* write = fopen("output.extension", "w+b");
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
     fseek(write, i, SEEK_SET);
     fwrite(&loaded[i], sizeof(standard), 1, write);
   }
   fclose(write);
}
```

Comment: You only have so much space on the stack.  That amount should be platform-dependent.

Comment: Use `malloc()` to allocate large arrays.

Comment: If you're on Windows, the stack is usually limited to 1 MiB; if you're on a Unix-like system, the limit is usually larger  and often 8 MiB.  Either way, you run out of space on the stack — but your variable `unsigned char loaded[size];` is allocated on the stack. (Yes, the standard doesn't mention stack; it applies to most practical implementations, and to Windows specifically).  Use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` and `free()` to get bigger chunks of memory.

Comment: There is no reason to find the amount of data beforehand: use dynamic memory, via pointers. `realloc()` to ensure you have more memory available, and read until reading fails. (If then `ferror()` is false but `feof()` is true, you read all data available. Otherwise, `ferror()` is true, indicating there was a read error, and your program should abort.)

Comment: With `int size;  size = ftell(sizer);`, code has troubles when `ftell()` returns a value more than `INT_MAX`.  As `ftell()` returns a `long`, one limitation removal would be to use `long size = ftell(sizer);` and check its result.

Comment: If you need to load the whole file into (virtual) memory then you might wish to consider using *memory mapping*.  On UNIX-like systems that uses `mmap` and on Windows `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`.

Comment: As file size can exceed memory space, code could consider not reading all the file before processing it.

Comment: The direct answer to "Do arrays have a maximum dimension?" Yes, `SIZE_MAX`, yet various platforms also have other more severe limitations.

Comment: Ok. I solved using malloc() and free() functions. I finally understood their importance. I will try other methods suggested. Thank you guys for your time. Now I need to improve the speed, it seems rather slow.

Comment: Remove all `fseek` calls to make this faster.